# what should be the output for below program?

Tags: c, output

```
void foo(int n, int sum)
{

  int k = 0, j = 0;

  if (n == 0) return;

  k = n % 10;

  j = n / 10;

  sum = sum + k;

  foo (j, sum);

  printf ("%d,", k);

}

int main ()

{

  int a = 2048, sum = 0;

  foo (a, sum);

  printf ("%d\n", sum);

  getchar();

}
```

For me this should be 4,0,2,8,0
However, when i execute it, it gives me 2,0,4,8,0

Comment: Step through a debugger. Show some effort, please.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  
Please take the tour stackoverflow.com/tour,  
learn asking good questions stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
If you are looking for help with debugging code see https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is called as recursive call to the function.

And internally Recursion run as a `stack` LAST IN FIRST OUT kind

Now in your case it is first printing the output of last call to `foo` function

Steps in which your program is executing are like this and result  will go in stack

1 - 1 st call to `foo` value of `k = 8`

2 - 2 nd call to `foo` value of `k = 4`

3 - 3 rd call to `foo` value of `k = 0`

4 - 4 th call to `foo` value of `k = 2`

And as told earlier it will work like stack so the output of the program will be 
`2 0 4 8`  and if you want `4,0,2,8,0` this as a output you need to write the logic accordingly :)

Comment: If so you can accept it as answer to your question. Or increase the flag :)

Answer (score 1):

As the code stands, the argument `sum` to `foo` is not really relevant since it is passed by value so the last statement in the main function `printf ("%d\n", sum)` will print `0` regardless of what happens inside `foo`. That's the last `0` you see in the output the program generates.

Now, the function `foo` itself accepts an argument `n`, performs integer division by 10, and recursively calls itself until `n` is zero. This in effect means that it will print the decimal digits of the input number which is what you see in the output...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the output you are getting is absolutely right.

In `main()`,`foo()` is called with `a=2048` and `sum=0`.

In `foo()` we have `n=2048`, then the if condition calculates values for `k`,i.e.,(`n%10`) and `j`,i.e.,(`n/10`) till `n` becomes equal to `0`.

Now since there is a recursive call to `foo()` with `j` and `sum` as parameters, the value of `k` in each iteration gets pushed to a stack and is popped out when `n==0` condition is satisfied.

So, if you trace out the program you get values of `k=8,4,0,2` which is pushed to stack in the same sequence and thus while popping the elements we have `2,0,4,8`.

Comment: Thank you. This make sense :)